# Overlay Ui in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, overlay

i am a beginner in android studio , i want overlay like this
can anyone suggest me , how can i achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNZVo.jpg) .it will be very helpful for me , Thank You